# Cannot fill in missing values with conditional statement pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a *dataframe* that has columns of attributes of male and female. There is a column `df['long_hair']` with `0=no` and `1=yes`. I want to fill the missing values in this column with respect to it's gender. This is my code. But, the problem is, the inplace does not work with conditional statement column. So how can I do this?

```
df[df['Male']==1]['long_hair'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

This code means get the people who are male and fill the missing values with 0 (meaning they don't have long hair).

Comment: Does `df.loc[df['Male']==1,"long_hair"].fillna(0,inplace=True)` work?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried applying lambda functions but it does not fill up the missing values.

Comment: you can of course always just asign it directly i.e `df.loc[df['Male']==1,"long_hair"] =df.loc[df['Male']==1,"long_hair"]. fillna(0)` but it's weird the inplace does not work

Comment: Yeah somehow I have got it but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass it with assigning using [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html)

> cond bool Series/DataFrame, array-like, or callable
> Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other. If cond is callable, it is computed on the Series/DataFrame and should return boolean Series/DataFrame or array. The callable must not change input Series/DataFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).

```
df.long_hair = df.long_hair.where((df.Male != 1) | df.long_hair.isnull())
```

This will keep the values when it is not male or not null.

Comment: I didn't know about that! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @aliffnabil You're welcome. Fee free to accept the answer if it addressed your question.